# Handling error in HTTP POST

Tags: node.js, http, post

I have code that hits a `POST` URL and receives the data. Below is the code:

```
var postdata="{u:1}";
var options = {
                 host: 10.0.0.1,
                 port: 80,
                 path: /ddd,
                 method: post
            };
var reqClient = http.request(options, function(res)   
            {

                  var data = '';
                  res.setEncoding('utf8'); 
            });
 //setting the request contenet type to application/json
            reqClient.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            //Posts the data to the Server
            reqClient.write(postData);
            reqClient.end();
reqClient.on('response', function (res) 
                {   
                      var data = '';
                      res.on('data', function (chunk) 
                      {   
                            data+=chunk;                            
                      });
res.on('end',function(){
//Perform some functions
});
}).on('error', function(){
                        //error handler
                    }); ;
```

I have to handle an error, say when the server is not able to hit the client URL. Can I follow the above approach? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add another event listener for the error event which is detailed on the [Node.js HTTP Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

```
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```